# Entity Framework Code First generates two foreign key columns in database when creating a 1:n relationship

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I want to create an 1:n relationship, **based on the naming conventions** for creating relationships, with the Entity Framework. I'm using codefirst. Entity Framework ignores the conventions and alwas creates two foreign key columns, instead of only one:

- StreamWorkerUser_Id  (i want only this column)
- StreamWorkerUser_Id1

The configuration class is configured like following:

```
AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
```

I'm using the Microsoft.Identity Framework, with custom classes for all models.

My DbContext class is as simple as following.

```
public class StreamWorkerDataContext : IdentityDbContext<StreamWorkerUser, StreamWorkerRole, int, StreamWorkerUserLogin, StreamWorkerUserRole, StreamWorkerUserClaim>
{
    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

The `Task` model:

```
public class Task : StreamWorkerEntity
{
    public StreamWorkerUser StreamWorkerUser { get; set; }
}
```

The `StreamWorkerUser` model:

```
public class StreamWorkerUser : IdentityUser<int, StreamWorkerUserLogin, StreamWorkerUserRole, StreamWorkerUserClaim>
    {
        public virtual List<Task> Tasks { get; set; } // also tested ICollection
    }
```

The `Task` class inherits from this base type, here are also two properties of type `StreamWorkerUser` defined (But these columns generated correctly in the database.):

```
public class StreamWorkerEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Updated { get; set; }
    public StreamWorkerUser Creator { get; set; }
    public StreamWorkerUser LastEditor { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible that, the properties `Creator` and `LastEditor` disturbing the database migration?

Do i understand the conventions correctly?

Much more information:

- Entity Framework Version 6.1.3
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.2.1
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework 2.2.1
- ASP.NET 4 MVC 5
- SQL Server in Azure Cloud
- C# 6.0
- .NET Framework 4.5.2
- *All of this code is in a class libary*

Comment: how do you then want to store relations to Creator and LastEditor if you want only one foreign key?

Comment: @faint220 I don't want only one foreign key. There should be three. One for `Creator`, one for `LastEditor` and one for `StreamWorkerUser`. Currently there are 4 columns generated: Creator_Id, LastEditor_Id, StreamWorkerUser_Id, StreamWorkerUser_Id1.

Comment: Have you tried entity type configuration??? You can explicitly declare the foreign key using fluent api

Comment: I got the problem. Your task has a StreamWorkerUser, also inherits from StreamWorkerEntity which has another field of type StreamWorkerUser. All in all, StreamWorkerUser has many Tasks and Task has 2 user(that is counted as many from database point of view). Your relation seems to be many:many  rather than 1:many. Naming convention does not care about the correctness of your relation logic. Re-analyze the concept of your classes and relations.

Comment: Take a loot at the answer I've posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59465609/ef-core-creates-multiple-foreign-key-columns

Answer (score 0):

So you might think that EF in this situation:

```
 public StreamWorkerUser Creator { get; set; }
 public StreamWorkerUser LastEditor { get; set; }
```

will create creator_id and lasteditor_id, but it doesn't, because EF took class name and made StreamWorkerUser_Id, and StreamWorkerUser_Id1, because there were StreamWorkerUser_Id already used. By default, if you make relation by class(not by int field), EF generates its column name depending on the class name(not by field name).

If you want to specify column names for those FK you can do :

```
    public int CreatorId { get; set; } //this field name will be column name
    [ForeignKey("StreamWorkerUser")]
    public StreamWorkerUser Creator { get; set; }

    public int EditorId { get; set; } //this field name will also be column name
    [ForeignKey("StreamWorkerUser")]
    public StreamWorkerUser Editor { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in my case the columnames are generated from the fieldname. Please see comment under the question.