# EF Core creates multiple foreign key columns

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core with .NET Core 3.1

I have simple example of Client-Event relationship:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }

}

public class Client : BaseEntity
{
    
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

}

public class Event : BaseEntity
{

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

In my context, I'm using Fluent API to specify relationships:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        
    modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
        .HasOne<Client>()
        .WithMany()
        .IsRequired()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

}
```

When I create migration, the client table looks fine, but the event table looks like this:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Events",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                CreatedOn = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                ModifiedOn = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: true),
                Start = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                End = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                ClientId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                ClientId1 = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Events", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Events_Clients_ClientId",
                    column: x => x.ClientId,
                    principalTable: "Clients",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Events_Clients_ClientId1",
                    column: x => x.ClientId1,
                    principalTable: "Clients",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });
```

Finally I end up having two columns: **ClientId** and **ClientId1**. Why is Entity Framework creating two columns for my relationship?

I wasn't using Fluent API so far and it worked perfectly with just shadow property ClientId auto-generated, but I needed to configure cascade delete form this entities, and since there is no other way to do it, I specified the relationship as pictured above. Since then, there is additional foreign key column for it.

I tried specifying a foreign key column:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
            .HasOne<Client>()
            .WithMany()
            .IsRequired()
            .HasForeignKey("ClientId")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

No effect so far. Is there any way to tell EF im using auto generated shadow properties?

Edit #1:

I also tried specyfing Foreign keys properties on my own like this:

```
public class Event : BaseEntity
{

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
    .HasOne<Client>()
    .WithMany()
    .IsRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.ClientId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

but there is still no effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out, relationships can be empty - leaving decision to the framework, but it doesn't really serve Your interest. I modified my code, so there is explicit pointing at the navigation property, and EF recognized the relationship and stopped creating shadow properties for the columns:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
    .HasOne<Client>(e => e.Client)
    .WithMany()
    .IsRequired()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
{

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public int? ClientId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClientId ")]
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Actually I've tried this, but unfortunately it wont work. It will only tell EF that it should look for the ClientId property in the Event entity, but since there is no property explicitly declared and im counting on the framework itself that it will create it - it wont have effect whether I let the framework create it or will create it by myself. FluentAPI will not recognize this as relationship and wil force creation of new property

Comment: Try this one, without  <Client>
```c# .HasOne(e => e.Client)